# Karaf bundle list does not display certain bundles

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

When I use the Karaf `bundle:tree-show` command to dig into the dependency trees of some of the bundles deployed in my Felix container, I see some bundles, e.g., `javax.jms-api [39]`, which do not appear when I run the `osgi:list -t 0 -s` command:

```
  ID │ State  │ Lvl │ Version                         │ Symbolic name
─────┼────────┼─────┼─────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────
...
  38 │ Active │  80 │ 1.2                             │ javax.interceptor-api
  41 │ Active │  80 │ 1.2                             │ javax.transaction-api
...
```

They are also inaccessible to commands such as `bundle:headers`, making it difficult to fetch the metadata I need from them.

What's going on here? Are these bundles just hidden somehow? How can I dig into their contents?

Comment: Can you give more context to replicate the problem (karaf version, features installed)?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider For reasons of confidentiality, I cannot give the full state of the system. I am asking how, in principle, this could happen.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with plain karaf?

Comment: I would say that you should always see all bundles with list -t 0 but for example in karaf 4.2.4 osgi:list is not even a known command. So the karaf version is crucial for helping you.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider It's a Fuse 7.2 deployment, which seems to use Karaf 4.2.0. The underlying container is Felix, but I can't quite figure out which version -- its core bundles are among the ones that I can't see. A fresh, empty deployment still exhibits the problem.

Comment: I just downloaded Apache Karaf 4.2.0 and did list -t 0 -s and I see all bundles. Btw even in karaf 4.2.0 there is no command osgi:list. It is bundle:list. Maybe this is a Fuse specific problem.

Comment: I have the same issue in Fuse 7.5.  "bundle:list -t 0" does not show the first 30 bundles, which are core bundles. Did you ever find a solution/explanation for this?